# Are there visual proofs for the sums of reciprocals of square and triangular numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a visual proof for the sum of the reciprocals of powers of 2 -

[image]

> Are there a similar proofs for reciprocals of square and triangular numbers?

I couldn't find any.

I don't know if I used the right terms; maybe it's: infinite series sum.

So correct this question if it's wrong.

Comment: For triangular numbers, notice that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {T_n} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n(n+1)} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac 1 n - \frac 1 {n+1} \right )$$
so you might want to look for visual proofs that the sum of the telescoping series is $1$.

Comment: For the reciprocal of squares, this seems unlikely as the sum is a transcendental number, hence not constructible.

Comment: The reciprocal of the squares can be visualized (and in a clumsy way) in $3D$ I think, and never in $2D$. Start by drawing a cube with side of length $1$ then above it  at its corner, draw a box of the same height $1$ but of a square face with length $\frac{1}{2}$ (it'll have the volume of $\frac{1}{4}$) and above it a box of height $1$ also and width=length$=\frac{1}{3}$ and so on ...

Comment: Luca Bressan - something like this - for triangular numbers? But probably not exactly; this looks as relating to harmonic-numbers.
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SumOfATelescopingSeriesII/#snapshot1